# Checking link attribute in watir -- Error as 'asserts_exists"?

Tags: watir

This is the link that I want to check using watir.

The code is within an `<a>` tag:

```
<a title="logout" href="admin/logout.aspx" Logout>
```

The code which i have included

```
ie.link(:href, "admin/logout.aspx").click
```

Error During execution

```
'assert_exists':Unable to locate the element,using {:tag name=}["a"],:href=>"admin/logout.aspx"}
(watir::Exception::Unknown object Exception)
```

Comment: If you output all links on the page, does the link you want appear in the list? You should be able to output all links with `puts ie.links.collect(&:href)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I remember, Internet Explorer converts all relative links ("admin/logout.aspx") to absolute ("http://site.com/admin/logout.aspx").

Try this:

```
ie.link(:href, /logout/).click
```

Comment: "did not work" does not help me help you. You will have to provide more data.

Comment: Thanks For your Reply...This is the link that i want to check using watir.

<a title="logout" href="admin/logout.aspx">Logout</a>

The code which i have included

ie.link(:href, "admin/logout.aspx").click

Error During execution

'assert_exists':Unable to locate the element,using {:href=>/Logout/,  :tag_name=>"a"}
(watir::Exception::Unknown object Exception) from C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver element/element.rb:118:in 'Click'from C:Ruby193/script.rb:16:in'<main>'

Comment: Can you provide link to the page, or a similar one where the problem can be reproduced? Is the link in a frame?

Comment: <div id="dvBanner" class="banners_admin">
<div style="background-color:#e8e6e3;height:26px; float:right; padding-right:10px;padding-left:10px;">
<span id="lblUser">Kumaran</span>
  |  
<a title="logout" href="admin/logout.aspx">Logout</a>
  |  
<a id="hylAdmin" href="admin/admin.aspx">Your Account Settings</a>
</div>   Code:     b.link(:text=>'Logout').click                                                              Kindly Select The Link ..I 'm Stucking here for two days..Plz Help Mr

Comment: And then link is not frame

Comment: not working nd also tried ie.div(:id =>"dvBanner").link(:text => "Logout").click

Answer (score 0):

```
ie.a(:text => "Logout").when_present.click
```

Comment: Please add some comment as to why this is a correct answer (if it is?) if you found it yourself. Thank you.

Comment: This would be typical of a link that is not actually within any of the HTML being initially loaded that composes the page, and is added later by javascript that is activated once the main page has been loaded.  Watir waits for the browser to say "I'm done getting the page from the server" before proceeding, but sometimes that can mean client side javascript is still processing, using .when_present waits until watir can see that element (e.g. it gets created by the javascript) before it tries to proceed